# Update event in ethereum contract

Tags: solidity

I have define update status event in my contract which basically print `vote casted` whenever transaction happen , however I am unable to see my event getting fired neither in my console or in testrpc console. Only thing I am getting is transaction id and timestamp. What's wrong I am doing here?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Voting {

mapping (bytes32 => uint8) public votesReceived;

address sender;

bytes32[] public candidateList;
event Updatestatus (string _msg,address sender);
function Voting(bytes32[] candidateNames) {
candidateList = candidateNames;
}

function totalVotesFor(bytes32 candidate) returns (uint8) {
   if (validCandidate(candidate) == false) throw;
return votesReceived[candidate];
}

function voteForCandidate(bytes32 candidate) payable {
   if (validCandidate(candidate) == false) 
   throw;
   else{
   Updatestatus("First vote casted by",msg.sender);
   votesReceived[candidate] += 1;

 }
 }

   function validCandidate(bytes32 candidate) returns (bool) {
     for(uint i = 0; i < candidateList.length; i++) {
   if (candidateList[i] == candidate) {
    return true;
    }
   }
   return false;
   }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a framework like [**Truffle**](http://truffleframework.com/) makes your life easier as it abstracts most the complexity.

The result using the Truffle JS testing tools shows that your contract is correct and the event is triggered:
[image]

I pushed the code into my Github if you want the whole project: [here](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/22847-update-event-in-ethereum-contract)

---

Here is the details:

**1. Initialisation**

Init a Truffle project and create a sample contract (Metacoin)

```
truffle init
```

**2. Contracts**

Copy your contract in the folder */contracts*

**3. Migration**

The migration step corresponds to the deployment of the contracts on a blockchain (test-rpc, testnet, mainnet, ...). By default it deployed on an rpc-url localhost:8545 which points on test-rpc in my case

Then the file */migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js* is used to code your deployment script

```
var Voting = artifacts.require("./Voting.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Voting, ["greg", "bob", "tom"]);
};
```

To deploy on the blockchain, just run the following command

```
truffle migrate
```

**4. Testing the contract**

Truffle includes a Javascript testing tool. In */test/Voting.js*

```
var Voting = artifacts.require("./Voting.sol");
contract('Voting', function(accounts) {

    it("test1", function() {
        var votingInstance;

        return Voting.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            votingInstance = instance;
            return votingInstance.voteForCandidate("greg", {from: accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(5, "ether")});

        }).then(function(tx) {
            console.log("Print events");
            console.log(tx.logs[0]);
        });
    });
});
```

To run the tests, simply execute:

```
truffle test
```

The callback of a transaction contains an object that includes logs (aka events):

```
{ tx: '0x76195a08487d0e1cc2dcd0518016165dbea87b3cb8aa935163d2b386597f0752',                              
  receipt:                                                                                               
   { transactionHash: '0x76195a08487d0e1cc2dcd0518016165dbea87b3cb8aa935163d2b386597f0752',              
     transactionIndex: 0,                                                                                
     blockHash: '0xf9fbed58551971facdfa504d5114725f0a78dcbbed78c76e03bf7b21b8a2a695',                    
     blockNumber: 32,                                                                                    
     gasUsed: 44355,                                                                                     
     cumulativeGasUsed: 44355,                                                                           
     contractAddress: null,                                                                              
     logs: [ [Object] ] },                                                                               
  logs:                                                                                                  
   [ { logIndex: 0,                                                                                      
       transactionIndex: 0,                                                                              
       transactionHash: '0x76195a08487d0e1cc2dcd0518016165dbea87b3cb8aa935163d2b386597f0752',            
       blockHash: '0xf9fbed58551971facdfa504d5114725f0a78dcbbed78c76e03bf7b21b8a2a695',                  
       blockNumber: 32,                                                                                  
       address: '0xe973ea06c0caa83807de42ab870b6102785c9a72',                                            
       type: 'mined',                                                                                    
       event: 'Updatestatus',                                                                            
       args: [Object] } ] }
```

Comment: Hey @Greg Thanks for your great answer. It works for me now. Just one more question I want to create a webpage and connect this truffle with my webpage so that I can see these transaction logs on my browser console .Any good tutorial for such scenarios. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: You can find some ready-to-use boxes (Truffle + React) [here](https://truffle-box.github.io/). If you want to use other frontend technologies, you can try the JavaScript library [truffle-contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract)